# Mongoid: Suppressing _id for embeds_one?

Tags: mongoid

I'm looking for a way to suppress the generation of the _id field in the child class of an embeds_one association, but can't find a way to do it.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

If you create an embeds_one association for a child class, then the _id field is not required, since there will only ever be one child embedded in the parent.

Mongoid 7.0, MongoDB 4.2.

This is easy when using Mongoose in the NodeJS/Javascript ecosystem. You just specify

```
{ _id: false }
```

in the options for the Mongoose schema.  Looking for a similar thing for Mongoid in the Ruby on Rails world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid internally defines the _id field on each document with a default value, but you can redefine this field to not have a default value.

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :bar
end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :foo

  field :_id, type: String
end
```

Comment: Thanks....but what I want to do is to eliminate the _id field for embeds_one child classes, since it's extraneous (the parent _id is sufficient if we need one), since there is only one and it's embedded.  I don't want to redefine it to another type.

Comment: Do not confuse the presence of the field definition with the presence/storage of data in said field.